# I have a navigation menu item whose content is "a" tag whose class is class="section-link" , How can I add popover-link-a to class definition from js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

If the grid in the body has no data then I want to show pop-up information on the menu `li` component. I show pop-up by adding `popover-link-a` class

current situation:

```html
<li id="tecrube" runat="server"><a href="#tecrube" class="section-link">İş Tecrübesi</a></li>
```

make as follows with javascript in runtime

```html
<li id="tecrube" runat="server">
  <a
    class="popover-link-a section-link"
    href="#tecrube" data-toggle="popover"
    title="İş Tecrübesi"
    data-content="İş Tecrübesi Boştur !"
    data-original-title="İş Tecrübesi" onclick="javascript:return false;">
    </i>İş Tecrübesi
  </a>
</li>
```

my nav menu is as follows:

```html
<div class="span3 ozgecmis-sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-sidenav" id="ozgecmis-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#kisisel" class="section-link">Kişisel Bilgiler</a>
    </li>
    <li id="navIletisimBilgileri" runat="server">
      <a href="#iletisim" class="section-link">İletişim Bilgileri</a>
    </li>
    <li id="navKisiselDurum" runat="server">
      <a href="#kisisel-durum" class="ozgecmis-tree-toggler section-link">Kişisel Durum</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-tree-inner" id="kisisel-durum-tree-inner">
        <li>
          <a href="#kisisel-engel" class="section-link">Engelli Durumu</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#kisisel-eskihukumlu" class="section-link">Eski Hükümlülük</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#kisisel-oncelik" class="section-link">Öncelik Durumu</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#ogrenim" class="section-link">Öğrenim Bilgileri</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#meslek" class="section-link">Meslek Bilgileri</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tecrubeMenu" runat="server" Visible="true">
      <a href="#tecrube" class="section-link">İş Tecrübesi</a>
    </li>
    <li id="navTercih" runat="server">
      <a href="#tercih" class="section-link">İş Tercihleri</a>
    </li>
    <li id="navBelgeler" runat="server">
      <a href="#belgeler" class="section-link">Kişisel Belgeler</a>
    </li>
    <li id="navEkOzellik" runat="server">
      <a href="#ekozellik" class="ozgecmis-tree-toggler section-link">Ek Özellikler</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-tree-inner" id="ekozellik-tree-inner">
        <li>
          <a href="#ekozellik-egitimkurs" class="section-link">Eğitim ve Kurs</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#ekozellik-nitelik" class="section-link">Nitelik</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="navYabanciDil" runat="server">
      <a href="#yabancidil" class="section-link">Yabancı Dil</a>
    </li>
    <li id="navSinav" runat="server">
      <a href="#sinav" class="ozgecmis-tree-toggler section-link">Sınav Bilgileri</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-tree-inner" id="sinav-tree-inner">
        <li>
          <a href="#sinav-osym" class="section-link">ÖSYM Sınavları</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#sinav-ozel" class="section-link">Diğer Sınavlar</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="navReferans" runat="server">
      <a href="#referans" class="section-link">Referanslar</a>
    </li>
    <li id="navDosyaEkle" runat="server">
      <a href="#dosyaekle" class="section-link">Dosyadan Özgeçmiş Yükleme</a>
    </li>
    <li id="navEkHizmetler" runat="server">
      <a href="#ekhizmetler" class="section-link">Ek Hizmetler</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a runat="server" id="hrefOzgecmisGoruntule" href="~/Ozgecmis/OzgecmisGoruntule.aspx" target="_blank" class="section-link">
        <b>Özgeçmiş Görüntüle</b>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS selector, you can find all 'anchors' with class of 'section-link' :
querySelectorAll("li>a.section-link");

mdn for node object, parentElement property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement

mdn for dataset usage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```js
function setClass() {
  document.querySelectorAll("li>a.section-link").forEach((item) => {
    let parent_li = item.parentElement;
    console.log(`${parent_li} is parent of ${item}`);
    item.classList.add('popover-link-a');
    item.dataset.originalTitle = "İş Tecrübesi"; // etc...
  });
};
setClass();
```

```html
<div class="span3 ozgecmis-sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-sidenav" id="ozgecmis-nav">
    <li><a href="#kisisel" class="section-link">Kişisel Bilgiler</a></li>
    <li id="navIletisimBilgileri" runat="server"><a href="#iletisim" class="section-link">İletişim Bilgileri</a></li>
    <li id="navKisiselDurum" runat="server">
      <a href="#kisisel-durum" class="ozgecmis-tree-toggler section-link">Kişisel Durum</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-tree-inner" id="kisisel-durum-tree-inner">
        <li><a href="#kisisel-engel" class="section-link">Engelli Durumu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#kisisel-eskihukumlu" class="section-link">Eski Hükümlülük</a></li>
        <li><a href="#kisisel-oncelik" class="section-link">Öncelik Durumu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#ogrenim" class="section-link">Öğrenim Bilgileri</a></li>
    <li><a href="#meslek" class="section-link">Meslek Bilgileri</a></li>
    <li id="tecrubeMenu" runat="server" Visible="true"><a href="#tecrube" class="section-link">İş Tecrübesi</a></li>
    <li id="navTercih" runat="server"><a href="#tercih" class="section-link">İş Tercihleri</a></li>
    <li id="navBelgeler" runat="server"><a href="#belgeler" class="section-link">Kişisel Belgeler</a></li>
    <li id="navEkOzellik" runat="server">
      <a href="#ekozellik" class="ozgecmis-tree-toggler section-link">Ek Özellikler</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-tree-inner" id="ekozellik-tree-inner">
        <li><a href="#ekozellik-egitimkurs" class="section-link">Eğitim ve Kurs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ekozellik-nitelik" class="section-link">Nitelik</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="navYabanciDil" runat="server"><a href="#yabancidil" class="section-link">Yabancı Dil</a></li>
    <li id="navSinav" runat="server">
      <a href="#sinav" class="ozgecmis-tree-toggler section-link">Sınav Bilgileri</a>
      <ul class="nav nav-list ozgecmis-tree-inner" id="sinav-tree-inner">
        <li><a href="#sinav-osym" class="section-link">ÖSYM Sınavları</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sinav-ozel" class="section-link">Diğer Sınavlar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="navReferans" runat="server"><a href="#referans" class="section-link">Referanslar</a></li>
    <li id="navDosyaEkle" runat="server"><a href="#dosyaekle" class="section-link">Dosyadan Özgeçmiş Yükleme</a></li>
    <li id="navEkHizmetler" runat="server"><a href="#ekhizmetler" class="section-link">Ek Hizmetler</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" id="hrefOzgecmisGoruntule" href="~/Ozgecmis/OzgecmisGoruntule.aspx" target="_blank" class="section-link"><b>Özgeçmiş Görüntüle</b></a></li>
  </ul>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors Mozilla Developer is hugely valuable resource for all things web tech!  Read up on CSS selectors, they are critical to writing clean code, so useful! and powerful :D

Comment: How can I do this for certain li item <li id="tecrubeMenu" runat="server" Visible ="true"><a href="#tecrube" class="section-link">İş Tecrübesi</a></li>

Comment: I want to add popover item for a certain menu li and add data content and data-original-title fields with js . How can I do this ?

Comment: Hi, I thought I had deleted this answer because it did not answer your question, whoops.  well, looking at what you have, the anchor element is what needs to be modified or at least what you are identifying with "section-link", so you can work backwards from there. I will update my answer to show.

Comment: My answer has been updated, within the forEach loop, you have a reference to the anchor and list item elements.

Comment: Hey! I've updated the answer again. Is this helping at all? It'd be great to have an upvote ;) maybe even mark as answer